# Section Header of UITableview not pin at the top when scroll up - Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

Normally, When I create table with style grouped, there are no any problem with section header. when I scroll up, the section header always stay at the top even when scroll pass it. I create one sample tableview using group style, section header not stay at the top when I scroll up like before. maybe do I miss some properties?.

Comment: Can you share that sample?

Comment: thank @richie for comment. sorry I cannot upload my sample project, because my internet very slow. can you create one very sample tableview project with section header than share it, I just wonder why or do I miss some properties.?

Comment: make sure `style` is set to `Plain` not `Grouped`

Comment: it's my bad. I set style to grouped.  now I understood it. thank q @richie

Comment: yes, but anyway pls vote up my question, thank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `style` is set to `Plain` not `Grouped`.

Check below image:

[image]